# CF - Button when pressed receives a focus (bold border)

Tags: compact-framework, button, focus

As the question is asked ... how can i prevent that from happening?
I have ZOOM IN and ZOOM OUT button that receive focus after pressed.

The button in CF does not have focus property so im guessing im required to do another painful workaround...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way the system draws the buttons when clicked. If you don't want this you'll have to redraw the button (and it various states) yourself

Comment: thanx Matt. As i expected ... sigh.

Comment: @no9 Have a look at OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.Button2 from http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/  - I've used this to work around this issue in Windows Mobile

Comment: thanx for the tip Matt. I dont feel comfortable mixing controls with OpenNETCF controls. Maybe if i would use them from the start it would work for me, but now i have several "self-made" controls. Its a shame that CF comes with such limitations ... Btw ... i created my own "ImageButton" and the focus does not get handled in my onPaint.